# Three.js: Make image texture fit object without distorting or repeating

Tags: three.js

I'm loading a .png file and displaying it as a texture on a rectangular surface. The aspect ratio of the .png and the aspect ratio of the surface are not the same. I need the texture to fit the object

- without repeating
- without distorting, i.e. maintaining its aspect ratio
- positioned at the center
- The height of the texture should be scaled up or down to the height of the object.

(For those familiar to CSS, I'm trying to achieve the equivalent of `background-size: auto 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;`.)

So far I am doing

```
tex1.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping
tex1.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping
repeatX = (clothWidth * textureSetting.h / (clothHeight * textureSetting.w))
repeatY = 1
tex1.repeat.set repeatX, repeatY
```

`clothHeight` and `clothWidth` are the dimensions of the object, `textureSetting.w` and `textureSetting.h` are the dimensions of the texture.

The texture is distorted and offset to the right.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; texture.repeat.x = geometryAspectRatio / imageAspectRatio; texture.offset.x = 0.5 * ( 1 - texture.repeat.x );` Is your image aspect ratio guaranteed to be greater than your geometry aspect ratio?

Comment: No it's not guaranteed. Have not tested the other case yet, though.

Comment: @WestLangley I don't get this. What's the point of `repeat` when we're not repeating the image?

Comment: @kwyntes `texture.repeat` and `texture.offset` scale and translate the geometry uv's so the texture is rendered as desired.

Comment: @WestLangley wait so what does `texture.repeat` do exactly then? [According to the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=texture#api/en/textures/Texture.repeat) it's just for tiling.

Comment: @kwyntes See https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_rotation.html.

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work just as @WestLangley suggested. Here's the solution in CoffeeScript:

```
tex1.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping
tex1.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
repeatX = (clothWidth * textureSetting.h / (clothHeight * textureSetting.w))
repeatY = 1
tex1.repeat.set repeatX, repeatY
tex1.offset.x = (repeatX - 1) / 2 * -1
```

And for anyone who prefers vanilla JavaScript, here is the JS Version:

```
var repeatX, repeatY;
tex1.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
tex1.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
repeatX = clothWidth * textureSetting.h / (clothHeight * textureSetting.w);
repeatY = 1;
tex1.repeat.set(repeatX, repeatY);
tex1.offset.x = (repeatX - 1) / 2 * -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

after years ! I change the code of @bootsmaat

It takes care if image is landscape or portrait.

```
const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(images[index].url, texture => {
var repeatX, repeatY;
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
if (texture.source.data.height < texture.source.data.width) {
  repeatX = squareWidth * texture.source.data.height / (squareWidth * texture.source.data.width);
  repeatY = 1;
  texture.repeat.set(repeatX, repeatY);
  texture.offset.x = (repeatX - 1) / 2 * -1;
} else {
  repeatX = 1;
  repeatY = squareWidth * texture.source.data.width / (squareWidth * texture.source.data.height);
  texture.repeat.set(repeatX, repeatY);
  texture.offset.y = (repeatY - 1) / 2 * -1;
}});
```