# Three.js - scaling background image to fit window, without stretching it

Tags: three.js, textures

When using `scene.background` the texture is stretched to fit the window size. 
I'm trying to reproduce the CSS cover attribute behavior as described on the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

> Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image.
>   If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped
>   either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.

I understand the `repeat` and `offset` texture attributes should be used, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Have you tried the proposed solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187035/three-js-make-image-texture-fit-object-without-distorting-or-repeating?rq=1

Comment: I just tried, thanks, but it's doesnt behave as a CSS cover background. However this might be a start, I need to dig a bit further the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same problem with you. After digging docs I resolved it. Below code should work for people struggle with this.

`targetWidth` is your surface or canvas width.
`imageWidth` is width of texture need fit to target.

```
const targetAspect = targetWidth / targetHeight;
const imageAspect = imageWidth / imageHeight;
const factor = imageAspect / targetAspect;
// When factor larger than 1, that means texture 'wilder' than target。 
// we should scale texture height to target height and then 'map' the center  of texture to target， and vice versa.
scene.background.offset.x = factor > 1 ? (1 - 1 / factor) / 2 : 0;
scene.background.repeat.x = factor > 1 ? 1 / factor : 1;
scene.background.offset.y = factor > 1 ? 0 : (1 - factor) / 2;
scene.background.repeat.y = factor > 1 ? 1 : factor;
```