# Maintain aspect on Three.js texture

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm trying to keep a texture centered when it's shown in a different sized box.

I've seen this answer

[Three.js: Make image texture fit object without distorting or repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187035/three-js-make-image-texture-fit-object-without-distorting-or-repeating?rq=1)

But it's not quite doing it for me.

```
  this.texture = new THREE.Texture(this.image)
  const vec = new THREE.Vector3()
  new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( this.rounded ).getSize(vec)
  const imageAspect = this.image.width/this.image.height
  const boxAspect = vec.x/vec.y

  this.texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  this.texture.offset.y =  0.5 * ( 1 - boxAspect/imageAspect )

  //texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; texture.repeat.x = geometryAspectRatio / imageAspectRatio; texture.offset.x = 0.5 * ( 1 - texture.repeat.x )

  this.texture.needsUpdate = true 
  this.rounded.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: this.texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } )
```

[image: small]

In this aspect the values are

```
Image: {width:399  height:275}
Texture: {width:1, height: 0.75}
```

[image]

In this aspect the values are

```
Image: {width:399  height:275}
Texture: {width:2, height: 1}
```

How do I fix it so the graphic is always central, maintains the aspect and is not distorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I got you correctly, here is an option of how you can center it:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(16, 9);
var planeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/758px-Canestra_di_frutta_(Caravaggio).jpg", tex => {
    //console.log(tex);
    //console.log(tex.image.width, tex.image.height);
    let imgRatio = tex.image.width / tex.image.height;
    let planeRatio = planeGeom.parameters.width / planeGeom.parameters.height;
    //console.log(imgRatio, planeRatio);
    tex.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping; // THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
    tex.repeat.x = planeRatio / imgRatio;
    tex.offset.x = -0.5 * ((planeRatio / imgRatio) - 1);
  })
});
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, planeMat);
scene.add(plane);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Addition: how to re-compute UVs for ShapeBufferGeometry

```
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh); // mesh with ShapeBufferGeometry
var size = new THREE.Vector3();
box.getSize(size);
var vec3 = new THREE.Vector3(); // temp vector
var attPos = mesh.geometry.attributes.position;
var attUv = mesh.geometry.attributes.uv;
for (let i = 0; i < attPos.count; i++){
    vec3.fromBufferAttribute(attPos, i);
    attUv.setXY(i,
    (vec3.x - box.min.x) / size.x,
    (vec3.y - box.min.y) / size.y
  );
}
attUv.needsUpdate = true; // just in case
```

Comment: thanks this isn't working for me. I get the textures tiled on the wider view.

Comment: Ahh. I think it's because the texture isn't power of 2. This is probably the right solution. I'll have to wait until the textures we get from the server are power of 2.

Comment: @beek Hm, in my example, the texture is not power of 2, but it works.

Comment: I'm using a ShapeBufferGeometry. Wonder if that's the problem. I can get it working on the first screen, but then it repeats multiple times across the second.  Power or 2 image didn't fix it either. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what you mean. You need to re-compute UV coordinates. Take a look at this forum topic: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/texture-on-dynamically-created-object/2994/8?u=prisoner849 and at the fiddle from my last post there. Added the code for re-computing of UVs in the answer.

Comment: Awesome got it working. For some reason the box was returning a different size from what it should be on the second example, possibly a timing issue. I used the original data and it works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Awesome got it working. For some reason the box was returning a different size from what it should be on the second example, possibly a timing issue. I used the original data and it works perfectly. Thanks so much!