# three.js : how to center a sampler2D texture in the fragment shader?

Tags: three.js, fragment-shader

I have a plane and I'm using a `THREE.ShaderMaterial` on this plane.

Inside my shader I'm calling a squared texture. I would like to modify its width and height (and position) so the texture acts like the css property `background-size: contains`.

Here's what inside my fragmentShader main function :

```
vec2 uv = vUv;
vec4 disp = texture2D(disp, uv);
```

So far my texture fits my plane, so its ratio is broken.
How can I make it fit inside my plane, and make it centered inside it ? Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60409146/4045502

Comment: And this forum topic: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/centered-background-texture/13079?u=prisoner849

Comment: @prisoner849 I tried those solutions, but it only seems to work when textures are directly called as a map attribute of your material. It doesn't work when texture are called inside a fragmentShader.

Comment: use the same principle of calculation in fragment shader

Comment: @prisoner849 I'm sorry I don't see any example on how to do it in glsl. Are there a repeat and offset values for example ?

Comment: maybe this forum topic: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-realize-that-there-is-a-gap-when-the-material-is-laid-and-this-gap-can-change-the-color-and-gap-width/12884/5?u=prisoner849 and this https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-change-the-gap-of-the-sawtooth-problem/12934?u=prisoner849